# Kundera persistence entity definition with partition key and cluster key

Tags: cassandra, kundera

I am trying to use Kundera for connecting to Cassandra. In my case I have an Entity X with Partition Key {A,B} and cluster key {C}.

We have multiple values of C for each A and B combination(primary key).

So in such case how should be define the entity?

```
@Embeddable
public class PrimayKey implements Serializable{

 @Column(name = "A")
     private String a;

     @Column(name = "B")
     private String b;
}




@Entity
@Table(name = "X")
public class X{


    @EmbeddedId
    private PrimayKey key;

    @Column(name = "C")
    private String c;

   @Column(name = "D")
    private String d;
}
```

Here if I go for a find by Primary Key its not working as we have multiple values of C and D for each A and B combination. In such case how should we define entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an embeddable for partition key and then use it as a field in primary key. Kundera will automatically read the entities and consider the fields other than partition keys as clustering keys.

Cassandra equivalent Primary key : ((A, B), C)

Entity :

```
@Embeddable
public class PartitionKey {

 @Column(name = "A")
 private String a;

 @Column(name = "B")
 private String b;

}

@Embeddable
public class PrimayKey {

 private PartitionKey key;

 @Column(name = "C")
 private String c;

}
```

Please refer this [sample entity](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/blob/trunk/src/kundera-cassandra/cassandra-core/src/test/java/com/impetus/client/crud/compositeType/EntityWithMultiplePartitionKey.java) for more info.